# Can't retrive cookies from prevous sessions with document.cookie (local HTML file)

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

So I have created a cookie which lasts past the session (expires in a few years just to be safe) I can read the cookie with 
`var variable = document.cookie`
but when I close Firefox and run the HTML file again the same code does not work. However, when I use the Firefox dev tools I can see that the cookie is still there. When I press the button to create the cookie again `document.cookie = "key=data; expires=Thu, 2 Jan 2020 12:00:00 UTC;"` the code can now read and display it! However, I need to be able to store info there so simply creating a new cookie every time I open the page is not viable.

It is completely likely that I've made a dumb mistake or overlooked something small. I would appreciate any suggestions for this problem or alternate ways to store data from a local HTML.

Thanks!

P.S. I also tried using a function to create another cookie with a different key in hopes that that would cause the document.cookie to update but no luck, it only displayed the new cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation was also reproduced in my environment. (Win10 + Firefox 62.0.3)

You can use localStorage API as an alternative way.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage